# Mysql monitoring using Prometheus and Grafana

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I need to monitor Mysql using Prometheus and Grafana;

Added mysqld exporter in the client server

while starting the mysqld in the client server it reports as :

```
time="2017-09-05T11:42:53Z" level=info msg="Error scraping slave state: dial tcp [::1]:3306: getsockopt: connection refused" file="mysqld_exporter.go" line=824
time="2017-09-05T11:42:53Z" level=info msg="Error scraping table schema: dial tcp [::1]:3306: getsockopt: connection refused" file="mysqld_exporter.go" line=836
```

In client server :

- I have downloaded the mysqld exporter
- Extracted it
- Created .my.cnf file

  [client]
  user=prom

  password=abc123
- Given permission to that user by using this command

  mysql> GRANT REPLICATION CLIENT, PROCESS ON *.* TO 'prom'@'localhost' identified by 'abc123';

  mysql> GRANT SELECT ON performance_schema.* TO 'prom'@'localhost';
- Executed  this command

  ./mysqld_exporter -config.my-cnf=".my.cnf"

Prometheus status page shows as **UP** condition for this.
In Grafana no data is loaded for MySQL

Comment: Is the server listening on port 3306 and accepting connections? Also, you're running the exporter process on the same host as the DB process, right?

Comment: 3306 port is in listen state and in the same server(db server) mysqld exporter is running in 9104 port.

Comment: > "Prometheus status page shows as UP condition for this"

Does this mean you can see mysql data on the prometheus dashboard, but not in grafana? Can you see MySQL metrics when running `curl localhost:9104/metrics`

Comment: Did you ever solve the issue? Running into the same problem.